# Prints filename as title for each subplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot three graphs in a row, but running into a weird behavior.

I am trying to print the filename out before each subplot of the loop.

```
for file in filenames:
        data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter = ",")
        x = np.mean(data,axis=0)
        y = np.min(data,axis=0)
        z = np.max(data,axis=0)
        f,(plot1,plot2,plot3) = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(20,5))
        print(file)
        plot1.plot(x)
        plot2.plot(y)
        plot3.plot(z)
```

The only problem for my program is that all the graphs are plotted after the `print(file)` statement. So it became something like following:

```
filename1
filename2
filename3

Graph1 Graph2 Graph3
Graph1 Graph2 Graph3
Graph1 Graph2 Graph3
```

What I wanted is :

```
filename1
Graph1 Graph2 Graph3

filename2 
Graph1 Graph2 Graph3

filename3
Graph1 Graph2 Graph3
```

I also tried to look up title for subplot, apparently, there isn't such attributes

Why does subplot only plotted after all the print statements? How do I print the graphs right after each filename is print? Is there a way that i can supply a title name for each subplot?

Comment: I suspect you use jupyter notebook or similar? (Because usually graphs don't "print".) If that is the case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365763/matplotlib-sequence-is-off-when-using-plt-imshow/49366556#49366556) might be what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `plt.suptitle(file)` instead of `print(file)`.

If you insist on printing, then force `plt` to render after each iteration by `plt.show()`

```
for file in filenames:
    data = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter = ",")
    x = np.mean(data,axis=0)
    y = np.min(data,axis=0)
    z = np.max(data,axis=0)
    f,(plot1,plot2,plot3) = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(20,5))
    print(file)
    plot1.plot(x)
    plot2.plot(y)
    plot3.plot(z)
    plt.show()
```